# Amending x axis in R to reflect actual data points rather than default range of points

Tags: r, plot, axis

[image]

I'd like to amend the x axis to reflect the actual data points in my data set rather than the default in R which is to use a range.  My actual data points are 1072, 1169, 1470, 1539, 1651, 1748, and 1771 (wavenumbers). I understand this has something to do with suppressing the axis and then adding back in one that is desired but I'm not certain where exactly to insert this into my code (see below). diane1 is my data set. Any help appreciated.

```
E <- ggplot(diane1, aes(x = Wavenumber, y = Absorbance, fill = Study.Group)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", bin_width=50)  
G <- E + labs(title = "Key Absorbance differences before and after treatment", x = "Wavenumber", y = "Absorbance (a.u)")  
G + guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth =2, keyheight = 1, reverse = TRUE))
G + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

Here is what I was hoping to do:

[image]

Comment: try `x=factor(Wavenumber)`

Comment: fab! and simple. thank you!

Comment: I'd like to post an updated plot as a result of your advice but not sure how to do this/or if it's allowed in the comments. Thanks for tidying up my original post :)

Comment: oh, just add the new link to your post and i'll expand it for you.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/u/0/107296582405645717964/posts/8x4NmfCLfqB